# Excel, I want my workday function to always pull the next Monday

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a simple calculation =workday(b12,1)
However, If this date lands on any day other than Monday, how do I make it show the date for the next Monday?

Comment: Do you want this to happen even if the following Monday is not a workday?

Comment: Good point...lets try to avoid holidays

Comment: This is a modification of Scott's answer, taking into account your changed requirements: `=WORKDAY(A1+7-WEEKDAY(A1),1)`. This works by finding the next workday after the Sunday following the workday returned by your formula, if this is in `A1`. You can replace both instances of `A1` by your formula, `WORKDAY(B12,1)`, if you don't need the true next workday elsewhere.

Comment: You haven't responded to Scott nor myself for several days: have you lost interest in your question?

Answer (score 2):

Use this to return the correct Monday:

```
=A1+7-WEEKDAY(A1,3)
```

[image]

Note:  See comments below as why Mondays are now pulling the next Monday.

Comment: This is showing me the Monday past, can it show the next Monday?

Comment: I am not getting it going a week back.  It always returns the next monday when it is not monday.

Comment: Aha I understand...what I need it to do is even if the date is Monday, it needs to return the next Monday...

Comment: You specifically stated `If this date lands on any day other than Monday, how do I make it show the date for the next Monday?` in your question `any day other than Monday` would contradict your comment.  Which do you want?

Comment: Understood, I wasn't clear...I need it to always return the next Monday...

Comment: Please update your original post to reflect that, so when I edit my answer I do not open myself to down votes as it will contradict what is being asked.

Comment: see edit to the formula.

Answer (score 0):

If your date is in A1 put this in B1 :

`=A1+7-MOD(WEEKDAY(A1)-2,7)`

Comment: I'm getting Sunday returned when I use that?  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I think I have it solved, I just added 1 to the equation...THANKS!

Comment: you're right!! my bad.. Congratulations upon solving it.. || btw I've updated my answer... Thanks for the heads up.. Really appreciate it. ( :

Comment: `=A1+9-MOD(WEEKDAY(A1),7)` gives the incorrect answer. For a Saturday in A1, it returns the Monday 9 days away.